# Insert to array new key/value php

Tags: php, arrays, json

How

```
$arr = array ();
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
       $arr[] = $obj;

// add new key/value in same index
$arr['key'] = 'value';

echo json_encode ($arr);
```

In this construction not be result like I need

```
{
    0 =     {
        author = 3;
        id = 3;
        reader = 3;
        review = 4;
    };
    key = "value";
}
```

I need:

```
{
    author = 3;
    id = 3;
    reader = 3;
    review = 4;
    key = "value";
}
```

Comment: You can only get the desired output if there is only 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your query is only returning 1 row, so you don't need the while loop.

First things first though, please don't use `mysql_*`. Look into [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.pdo.php)

This is what you want instead:

```
$db = new mysqli(/* host, user, pass, db */);
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM aTable LIMIT 1");

$arr = $result->fetch_assoc();
$arr['key'] = 'value';
```

Edit: Ima go ahead and force you to use mysqli...

Answer (score 1):

Move the value-assigning code into the loop, if you need to add some key-value pair to each and every item of the resulting array:

```
$arr = array ();
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result))
  $obj->key = 'value';
  $arr[] = $obj;
}
```